# BootBox javascript Confirm delete

Tags: javascript, confirm, bootbox

I am using asp.net MVC 5.

In [Bootbox js](http://bootboxjs.com:)

```
 $(document).on("click", ".MyLink", function (e) {
     bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
     Example.show("Confirm result: "+result);
     }); 
});

@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CustomerID }, new { @class = "MyLink" })
```

How to delete the `HTML action link` ?
Please find the full details of the code:-

Javascript code:-

```
<script src="~/Scripts/bootbox.min.js"></script>

    $(document).on("click", ".MyLink", function (e) {
        var self = this;
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (result) {
            Example.show("Confirm result: " + result);
            $(self).remove();
        });
    });
```

HTML Code:-

```
<h2>Index</h2>

  <p>Content here. <a class="MyLink" href=#>Alert!</a></p>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
```

Also see the inside`<table>`  code for your
reference:-

```
<table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th> First Name </th>
            <th> Last Name </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName) </td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName) </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CustomerID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.CustomerID }) |
                @*@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CustomerID, @class = "MyLink" })*@
                <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", new { id = item.CustomerID })" class="MyLink">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Also see the `Controller` code for your reference:-

```
public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Customer customer = db.Customers.Find(id);
        db.Customers.Remove(customer);
        db.SaveChanges();
        if (customer == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
        //return View(customer);
    }
```

Comment: `$('.MyLink').remove()` in the callback ?

Comment: @adeneo: In the `callback` means in Javascript code or somewhere else ?

Comment: Replace `Example.show` with the line above ?

Comment: @adeneo: It's just removed record when i clicked the link and no confirmation dialog box. I want `confirmation` dialog box also

Comment: And did you do it like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/t62dm32r/**

Comment: Actually, this is probably better -> **http://jsfiddle.net/t62dm32r/1/**

Comment: @adeneo: You told to replace that, that is why I removed the `Example.Show` line

Comment: I have no idea what `Example.show` does, but you have to at least keep the bootbox to have a bootbox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69115/discussion-between-nadeem-and-adeneo).

Comment: @adeneo: It is not working, same the data is deleted without confirmation message.